# android opengl es background image

Tags: android, opengl-es

Hi
I am using opengl to draw sprites for a game. When I draw the level background the game slows down. Is there a way I can draw the background separately? The background is just a simple image that does not change or animate and as such does not need to be drawn every frame.

Comment: Post some code. However, you always need to redraw your sprites (including backgrounds) every frame.

Comment: public void draw(GL10 gl) {
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0,vertexBuffer);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
 }     That is my draw method and I use .draw in my renderering code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
glSurfaceView = ...
glSurfaceView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_background);
glSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19009278/1186286